# Can't access images via web with Azure storage and Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, azure-storage

I want to access the path of the image/blog in the browser, I am using Django rest API and the package [Azure storage](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/azure.html), I tried to make the container storage public, but still had no luck in accessing the image, what could be wrong?

This is an example of the image I want to access, it's there in the storage but can't access it :

https://gu-stagineis.net/media/blog_images/images_3.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

- If you store your images in a container of a storage account and grant public to the container then you can access the images using a URL.
- First create a container under the `Containers`  tab in the storage and then set the access level to `container` .
  [image]
- Now click on the newly created container and then click on `upload`  and upload images in the container .

[image]

- Here I have uploaded two images If you click on the images a pop will immerge with the url of the that image
  [image]
- This url is publicly accessible and you can make get request to it in you django app

In Browser :
[image]

In Postman :
[image]

- you don't even need to go the storage account for url

the urls will be of format :

```
https://<Storage Acount Name>.blob.core.windows.net/<Container>/<Image Name>
```

[@Siddhartha Vikram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17485073/siddhartha-vikram) answer is also correct using the `azure storage.blob`

Comment: Hi Mohit, whenever I try this link in the browser, it just downloads the image, it doesn't show it , why ?

Comment: Can you please create and share a demo url with a demo image so that I can under the issue because here my urls are displaying the images I have even checked in other browsers too (edge, chrome, Firefox) all of them displaying the image and check on multiple devices too

Comment: Yes please here it is :
[image link](https://logsstagingguio.blob.core.windows.net/guio-storage-staging/res/blog_images/cell_division.jpeg), when you try to access it, it will just download in the browser , instead of it being visible

Comment: You can use this as well :
https://logsstagingguio.blob.core.windows.net/guio-storage-staging/res/blog_images/computer_shortcuts.png

In postman it just shows this :
https://ibb.co/yfWJcDV

Comment: can you please click on the image in the storage account and check whether the  Content-Type is set to image/png like this https://i.imgur.com/dLO42fH.png  because I think the browser is treating the images as some form of encoded file instead of an image  that's why it is downloading instead of displaying . The browser will only do this if the file it is receiving is not supported by the browser

Comment: This is the Content-type set : https://ibb.co/D83rg26. and I wonder why so ? to almost all images I have

Comment: Remember I have png, jpeg and PDFs, how best can I update all of them

Comment: I changes changed my content-type to` application/octet-stream` and even my URLs started to download . What you can do is change the content type to `image/png` for images(This is done in portal ) so that the browser will know that the file it is getting is a image and it will start displaying the image

Comment: The challenge here, I have lots and lots of images in different extensions, JPEG and PNG, so am looking for the way of how to set them